# Get storybook to read global variable

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, storybook, emotion

I'm playing with storybook and emotion:
I set some global css variable like this so that I can switch colors when I want different themes

```
import { themeSpliceType } from "../feature/themeSlice";

function globalStyle(theme: themeSpliceType) {
  return css({
    body: {
      padding: 0,
      margin: 0,
      "--main-color": theme.mainColor,
      "--background-color": theme.backgroundColor,
      "--util-color": theme.utilColor,
      "--warning-color": theme.warningColor,
    },
  });
}

export default globalStyle;
```

and than in the react component css file I used these variables. (It all looks fine in react)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIENG.png)

```
.filled_div {
  background-color: var(--util-color);
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 5px 1px 5px 1px;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
}
```

but in storybook, it can't really read these variables. And therefore it will display as it is transparent. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3SpU.png)

is there a way to solve it??

I'm trying to either add a default color to storybook or possibly make storybook to read the css variables.